# How to use pkg-config in qt for crosscompile

Tags: qt, opencv, pkg-config

Ater I have crosscompiled qt5.5.1 and opencv3.1.0 sucessfully, there also exists problem(upset!).

Let me say it in datail:

a.On my PC ubunutu, when compile qt programs with opencv , I usually have two ways,

the first is in qt IDE, I add two extra lines in .pro

```
#.pro
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += opencv
```

the second is in terminal, the command line for example:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
```

I know the reason why I can use pkg-config, when run

```
echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

I get:

```
:/usr/local/opencv-3.1.0/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opencv-3.1.0/lib/pkgconfig:
```

b. While for crosscompile, how can I use pkg-config?

I have tried to edit the /home/lmk/.bashrc by adding:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/pkgconfig
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

and then open a new terminal, run:

```
echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

which gives me:

```
:/usr/local/opencv-3.1.0/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opencv-3.1.0/lib/pkgconfig:/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/pkgconfig
```

The problem is:
First,when in qt IDE and edit the .pro

```
#.pro
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += arm-opencv
```

the result is:

```
:-1: error: arm-opencv development package not found
```

Second,when in terminal:

```
arm-linux-g++ `pkg-config arm-opencv --cflags --libs` show.cpp -lpthread -lrt -o show

/home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.5.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: warning: libavcodec.so.57, needed by /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_highgui.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.5.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: warning: libavformat.so.57, needed by /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_highgui.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.5.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: warning: libavutil.so.55, needed by /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/li/libopencv_highgui.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.5.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: warning: libswscale.so.4, needed by /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_highgui.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.5.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: warning: libjpeg.so.9, needed by /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.5.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: warning: libpng16.so.16, needed by /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_set_defaults@LIBJPEG_9.0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_dict_free@LIBAVUTIL_55'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_alloc_huff_table@LIBJPEG_9.0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_set_expand_gray_1_2_4_to_8@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_free_context@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_read_end@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_write_info@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_set_swap@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_set_gray_to_rgb@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_open_input@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `sws_getCachedContext@LIBSWSCALE_4'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_write_trailer@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateCompress@LIBJPEG_9.0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_free@LIBAVUTIL_55'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_read_info@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_find_stream_info@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avio_open@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_guess_codec@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_set_quality@LIBJPEG_9.0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avpicture_get_size@LIBAVCODEC_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_read_image@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_src@LIBJPEG_9.0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_create_read_struct@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_set_rgb_to_gray@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_set_filter@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_frame_free@LIBAVUTIL_55'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_log_set_level@LIBAVUTIL_55'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_init_io@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_set_IHDR@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_get_IHDR@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_free_packet@LIBAVCODEC_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_create_write_struct@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_read_update_info@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_seek_frame@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_write_frame@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avpicture_fill@LIBAVCODEC_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_resync_to_restart@LIBJPEG_9.0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_compress@LIBJPEG_9.0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_get_tRNS@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_dict_set@LIBAVUTIL_55'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_rescale_q@LIBAVUTIL_55'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_get_riff_video_tags@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_decompress@LIBJPEG_9.0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_write_end@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_get_context_defaults3@LIBAVCODEC_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_network_init@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_write_header@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_set_read_fn@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_set_bgr@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_get_mov_video_tags@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `sws_freeContext@LIBSWSCALE_4'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_write_scanlines@LIBJPEG_9.0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_frame_alloc@LIBAVUTIL_55'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_read_header@LIBJPEG_9.0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `sws_getContext@LIBSWSCALE_4'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateDecompress@LIBJPEG_9.0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_compress@LIBJPEG_9.0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_find_encoder@LIBAVCODEC_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_start_decompress@LIBJPEG_9.0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_set_compression_strategy@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_init_packet@LIBAVCODEC_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_set_interlace_handling@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_set_strip_alpha@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_set_compression_level@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_reduce@LIBAVUTIL_55'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_malloc@LIBAVUTIL_55'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_encode_video2@LIBAVCODEC_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_freep@LIBAVUTIL_55'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avio_close@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_read_frame@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_flush_buffers@LIBAVCODEC_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_decode_video2@LIBAVCODEC_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_quality_scaling@LIBJPEG_9.0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_start_compress@LIBJPEG_9.0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_alloc_context@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_error@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_sub_q@LIBAVUTIL_55'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_guess_format@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_simple_progression@LIBJPEG_9.0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_new_stream@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `sws_scale@LIBSWSCALE_4'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_decompress@LIBJPEG_9.0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error@LIBJPEG_9.0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_write_image@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_find_decoder@LIBAVCODEC_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_dest@LIBJPEG_9.0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_register_all@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined  reference to `png_get_io_ptr@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined  reference to `png_set_write_fn@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined     reference to `avcodec_open2@LIBAVCODEC_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_set_packing@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_codec_get_tag@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_set_palette_to_rgb@PNG16_0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_lockmgr_register@LIBAVCODEC_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_default_qtables@LIBJPEG_9.0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_opt_set@LIBAVUTIL_55'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_calc_output_dimensions@LIBJPEG_9.0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_close@LIBAVCODEC_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_codec_get_id@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_close_input@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `jpeg_read_scanlines@LIBJPEG_9.0'
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `png_set_strip_16@PNG16_0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

In addtion, the crosscompiler is installed in

```
/home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin
```

crosscompile qt is installed in

```
/home/newdisk/optnew/qt5.5.1
```

crosscompile opencv is installed in

```
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm
```

crosscompile opencv's 3rdparty is installed in

```
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely
```

opencv's 3rdparty are:

```
zlib
jpeg
libpng
yasm
x264
xvidcore
ffmpeg
```

How should I set my environment variables to make pkg-config work well so that my programs can find opencv's as well as opencv-rely's include and lib directories?

Comment: If the 2.4.9 version of opencv is enough then you can install armhf packages from the Ubuntu repositories. Enable multiarch support in dpkg, install armhf versions of the packages alongside the usual amd64. I use a "third way" of setting up a project when doing multi-architecture builds - CMake (the .pro option should work too, but I've never used it).

Comment: Last night, I tried to add the opencv and opencv's 3rdparty libs to qt .pro with absolute path explicitly just like the anwser I posted below. I've got your meaing. Cmake is also a way for crosscopile. Whether qt or cmake is just a tool. I am a beginner, when I built opencv for my arm board, I touch cmake a little.@Velkan

Answer (score 0):

Last night, I tried the most direct way by adding the opencv and opencv's 3rdparty libs like this:

```
#.pro
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (3.0) Mon Nov 14 13:01:31 2016
######################################################################
QT += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = ImageShow
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
HEADERS += mywidget.h
SOURCES += main.cpp mywidget.cpp

INCLUDEPATH+=/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/include

LIBS += /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm/lib/libopencv_*.so \  //all opencv libs
        /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/lib/libavcodec.so \  //opencv's 3rdparty libs
        /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/lib/libavdevice.so \
        /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/lib/libavfilter.so \
        /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/lib/libavformat.so \
        /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/lib/libavutil.so \
        /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/lib/libjpeg.so \
        /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/lib/libpng.so \
        /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/lib/libpostproc.so \
        /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/lib/libswresample.so \
        /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/lib/libswscale.so \
        /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/lib/libx264.so \
        /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/lib/libxvidcore.so \
        /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/lib/libz.so
```

And I crosscompiled the qt programs and ran it on my arm board sucessfully, which also indicated that my configuration is right.

I wonder anyone of you have some simple ways for seraching relative libs, whether in qt or in cmake or just in termial. I am a green hand, and thanks for reply sincerely!